# How to get a ViewController to segue to itself repeatedly.

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

SWIFT: In my storyboard, embedded in a NavigationController, I have a ViewcontrollerA which needs to either present itself repeatedly OR present ViewcontrollerB based on an if clause.

I've implemented the logic in the prepareForSegue method.  I've drawn a segue from ViewcontrollerA to ViewControllerB.

```
    if (someClause == true)
    {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerA

    } else {

        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerB          
    }
```

Executing this code results the following error:
Could not cast value of type 'ViewControllerB' to 'ViewControllerA' .

That's because there is no segue from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerA. The segue is from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB.

Is there a way for one "Button" to have multiple segues?  One to ViewControllerA (itself) and one to ViewControllerB.  I know this is possible for TableViewCells.

Side note, I have managed to get instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier followed by a call to presentViewController to do what I want, but that destroys my NavigationStack and TabBar.  I DONT want to go this route because it seems like a lot of patch work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a segue between from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB, not the button to ViewControllerB.  Then do something like:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

if (someClause == true)
        {
            // Stay on ViewControllerA

        } else {

            performSegueWithIdentifier("showB", sender: AnyObject)         
        }
}

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showB") {
            let _ = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerB
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would I create a new instance of ViewControllerA and segue to it?  So for instance, when "someClause == true), I need to create a new ViewControllerA.  Can I create a segue from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerA?

Comment: What kind of data do you have in ViewControllerA?  Is it a tableView? Why do you need to create a new instance of it.

Comment: Yes it is a tableview... I'd like to create a new instance so 1) the navigation controller works properly.  Ie. push & pop off the stack. 2) that all variables are reset.

Comment: I am inclined to just say create and updateUI() function and do tableView.reloadData() to accomplish this.  However, are you saying it should have a back button to the prior version of ViewControllerA?  Maybe you can provide screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses!  Yes the navigation back button should take me back to the prior version of ViewControllerA.   So ViewControllerA(0) <--> ViewControllerA(1) ...... <--> ViewControllerA (n) <--> ViewControllerB.